# change smart card logon icons to two different icons

Tags: login, icons, authentication

We have two accounts mapped to our smart cards, a regular user account, and an admin account.
When logging in with our CAC, the logon icons are the same for both, and people are getting confused and logging in to the wrong account. Is there a way to change one of the icons? I found the .dll which references the smart card icon, but I can't figure out how to change it for just one account. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think I found a work around, if anyone else runs into this problem. I am going to "enable the Allow user name hint Group Policy setting". It will give the users the ability to type the account name, or hint, for the account they want to access. I would mark this as an answer but I can't answer my own question for 6 more hours.